# jquery count select inputs matching required value

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a (django-generated) form with the following content:

```
<form action="./" id="my_form" method="post">
...
<select name="object_0_status" id="id_object_0_status">
<option value="">---------</option>
<option value="1">Online</option>
<option value="2">Offline</option>
<option value="3">Unknown</option>
</select>
<select name="object_1_status" id="id_object_1_status">
<option value="">---------</option>
<option value="1">Online</option>
<option value="2">Offline</option>
<option value="3">Unknown</option>
</select>
<select name="object_2_status" id="id_object_2_status">
<option value="">---------</option>
<option value="1">Online</option>
<option value="2">Offline</option>
<option value="3">Unknown</option>
</select>
    ...
</form>
```

I am writing a custom validation method (using the JQuery Validations plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) that is cross-checking different entries on the form. In order to do this, I need to retrieve the number of select boxes which have their selected value set to '1' (e.g. online).

The select boxes are generated by a form factory, so there will be a variable number of them. There are also other select options on the form which should not be counted - just the ones ending '_status'.

What's the cleanest way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('select[id$=_status] option:selected[value="1"]').length;
```

see example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRwjR/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ends with selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
alert($('select[id$=_status]').find('option[value=1]').length);
```

That will go through all select boxes that end with `_status` in their ids and then `find` is used to find `option` in them whose value is set to `1`.

Comment: this doesn't find if the option is selected though... ?

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: Selected option will give you a length of 1 any way because only one option can be selected. The `:selected` filter selector can be used though for that.